# Google Apps Script to list all assignments of all Classes in Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-classroom

I need to list all the assignments of all the classes in Google Classroom. One line is not working, but I don't know how to fix it. It produces the error message `TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.` later on.

```
function listAssignments2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TAREAS');  

  var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var courses = response.courses;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];

// This line below is not written right, which gives me an error further on.
    var class = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(course.id);
  
}          

  var w = class.courseWork;
  var arr=[];

// The error comes out here stating "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.". 
  for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    var c = w[i];
    var ids = c.id;
    var user = c.creatorUserId;
    var type = c.workType;
    var ti = c.title;
    var des = c.description;
    var st = c.state;
    var sch = c.scheduledTime;
    var due = c.dueDate;
    arr.push([ids,user,type,ti,des,st,sch,due]); 
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);   

}
```

Comment: Your error likely stems from where you declare and assign a value to the 'w' variable. Investigate what is actually being returned by class.courseWork...it may not be an array.

Answer (score 1):

I was totally off on the order of what I was putting and on top of that I should have changed the two for loop variables.

```
function listAllAssignments() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TAREAS');  
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var courses = response.courses;

// First, the "arr" array had to be out of the for loop, this was the first error.
  var arr =[];

  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    var id = course.id;
    var class = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id);
    var w = class.courseWork;

/* The second and third error were here. First I had separated 
the for loops, when I should have put the second for loop inside 
the first, like I have here. Then, I should have changed the variable 
of the second for loop (like I did here with the "k"). This seems to 
have fixed the problems. */

        for (k = 0; k < w.length; k++) {
          var c = w[k]; 
          var ids = c.id;
          var user = c.creatorUserId;
          var type = c.workType;
          var ti = c.title;
          var des = c.description;
          var st = c.state;
          var sch = c.scheduledTime;
          var due = c.dueDate;
          arr.push([ids,user,type,ti,des,st,sch,due]);
          }
    }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

It could be that Classroom.Courses.list() is returning an empty response. In order to prevent that your script throws an error replace, use something like the following

```
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var courses = response.courses;
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id); // Replace this with operations to be don on each iteration
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }
```

By the way, the script on the question has a `for` statement that on each iteration assigns a new value to `class`. It's very likely that you should include the following lines inside the `for`'s code block:

```
  var w = class.courseWork;
  var arr=[];

// The error comes out here stating "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.". 
  for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    var c = w[i];
    var ids = c.id;
    var user = c.creatorUserId;
    var type = c.workType;
    var ti = c.title;
    var des = c.description;
    var st = c.state;
    var sch = c.scheduledTime;
    var due = c.dueDate;
    arr.push([ids,user,type,ti,des,st,sch,due]); 
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what happened, but something does not seem to be working with  var w = class.courseWork; Even when I put a concrete course ID in  var class = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(COURSE ID); it still says it cannot grab something, when I know this worked before. 

When I put var class = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(ID).courseWork;
  Logger.log(class); The result is undefined. (Putting a concrete ID in). That is where the problem is.

Comment: @JasonJurotich: Try the code from [Google Apps Script Quickstart | Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/apps-script) and let us know if it works on your environment.

Comment: Works perfectly. The error is in var class = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(ID).courseWork;

Comment: Update: something must have been affecting the script within Google's server, because I just tried it again and now it works, at least I got list of assignments from one class. Let me try and use the for loop again to get all the assignments from all of them.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the for loop gets cut off when a class has no assignments. I am going to experiment with try - catch and see if it will finish.